# Is eclipse uses proguard every built of project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, dex

i enabled proguard by adding below line into project.properties,

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

But i dont understand that when i click Run button, compiler uses proguard or not ?

If it is not, i need compiler to use proguard every project compiling, because i cant run my project or debeug my project.

i am getting an error from dex compiler,

> "[2014-04-09 16:46:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID
>   not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 [2014-04-09 16:46:04 - project] Conversion
>   to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536"

I found some article which says this problem can be solved by using proguard.

eclipse Version : 4.2.1

ADT Version     : 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826

Thank you very much
Talha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For build it will not use progruard, but when signing your apk using export eclipse uses proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard will be activated only if you sign and export your project. You can set your rules to obfuscate your code. But obfuscation will be processed when you export your project.